# Comparing the Ascii Code

Tags: java, ascii

I need to create a Morsealphabet and have to insert into a `BinaryTree`. I need to create `isLess` and `isGreater` methods. So this is like i started :

```
public boolean isLess(Buchstabe a) {
    if (a != null) {
        if (!a.isEqual(this)) {
            String aCode = a.getCode();
            if (aCode.compareTo(this.getCode()) > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}


public boolean isGreater(Buchstabe a) {
    if (!a.isEqual(this)) {
        String aCode = a.getCode();
        if (aCode.compareTo(this.getCode()) > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

So the Syntax should be that the . has to be less than the -
The  . and - can be handled as Strings so you should be able to compare `"."` and `"-.--"` where `"."` should be less than `"-.--"` - My solution gives me total bullshit. Do you have a solution that shoud work ?

Comment: pls post your      `getCode` Methode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel because `compareTo()` method is returning `0` if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than `0` if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than `0` if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string. So you don't need to make your own methods to do that

Supposing that your `getCode()` method gets the right code I would do this

```
String aCode = a.getCode();
int code = aCode.compareTo(this.getCode())
if (code == 0){ 
// they are equal 
}
if (code < 0){ 
// aCode is greater than this.getCode
}
if (code > 0){ 
// aCode is less than this.getCode 
}
```

Comment: I think I have a error in my thought. Is it possible that "--." is Less than "--" or do you know how i could solve this. I mean in the BinaryTree i have to go left if i have a "." and i need to go right if i have a "-".

Comment: Llexicographically ´--.´ will always be greather than ´--.´ If you have other requirements you always can add a nested `if` specifying `if (a.Code contains('.')) { //do stuff }`

Answer (score 0):

`".".compareTo("-")` gives me 1 so `"."` is considered to be greater than `"-"` in Java.

It should then be obvious that

```
if(aCode.compareTo(this.getCode())>0)
    return false;
```

returns false if `aCode` is greater than `this.getCode()` which is the oposite of what you want. Exchanging the `true` and `false` in your returns should do the trick.